# Run AJAX call on page exit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, dom

I've ran into a bit of a problem trying to run synchronous AJAX call using the event `$(window).unload`.

According to the documentation though:

> As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false is deprecated.

I'm trying to send the user's data (a name, an age and a large string of numbers) to a php file all in one go just before they exit the page.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Basically? Not reliably.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080269/javascript-before-leaving-the-page

Comment: Doesn't need to be that reliable, I'd be happy if it worked 90% of the time. It's not a duplicate, but thanks anyway - this question is about ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at these:

[Can the unload Event be Used to Reliably fire ajax Request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584288/can-the-unload-event-be-used-to-reliably-fire-ajax-request)

[Why can't I use jQuery to fire an AJAX request from an unload event handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274949/why-cant-i-use-jquery-to-fire-an-ajax-request-from-an-unload-event-handler)

[Running a PHP through Ajax on Unload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297750/running-a-php-through-ajax-on-unload)

Conclusion:

It's better not to have async request.
And you must set **ignore_user_abort()** in your php so it doesn't terminate when connection drops!

Answer (score 1):

You can try `beforeunload`,

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
//Do your processing
return "You want to close the window?"
});
```

Comment: My problem here is the ajax request, rather than the event triggering.

Answer (score 1):

I would not even try to do this if this data is important because there is no guarantee that even the `unload` event occurs. The person could shutdown the browser, pull the plu on the computer etc.

I would have a save button on the page instead.

Comment: The data isn't very important, I would be happy if it only worked 90% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you don't know if the browser will interupt the request before it leaves your computer. I think it depends on the browser. Almost for sure, there is no way for the client to handle the response.